# Directory structure of gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc

I have been using `gcc` on Linux for quite long, but I still don't know its internals. First of all, I would like to know where does the `glibc` resides. Secondly, where are the headers. I want to know the basic directory structure of `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

The header files are in `/usr/include/`. For more information on `GCC`, you might want to look through [gcc.gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/). It has a lot of information on GCC, the internals, and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)?

For example, on `Linux version 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51))` you can find the `glibc` shared objects in `/usr/lib/gcc` and in `/lib`:

```
locate libgcc
/lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 // symbolic link to 
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.1/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.1/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.1/libgcc_s.so
...
```

Includes are located in `/usr/include`:

```
>locate stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
/usr/include/bits/stdio.h
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/stdio.hpp
...
```

The files are almost in the same directories in `Linux version 2.6.38-13-generic (buildd@yellow) (gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) )` (x86_64 architecture):

```
locate libgcc
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1
/usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1.0.2
/usr/lib/ure/lib/libgcc3_uno.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/libgcc_s_32.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/32/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/32/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
...
```

```
locate stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
/usr/include/bits/stdio.h
/usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1/stdio.h
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good website to know the directory structure of gcc here : [Source Tree](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Source-Tree.html)

And about the headers, you can go there : [Headers GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Headers.html#Headers)